# php timeout on for loop with dates

Tags: php, date, for-loop, timeout

I want to get an array of dates within a period. To do so I thought up a for loop (seems simple enough...) But when I run it even with for the dates of 1 month it times out.

This is my php:

```
        $startdate = '2018-01-31';
        $recurring = '2';


        switch($recurring) {
            case '1':
                $period = '+1 day';
                break;
            case '2':
                $period = '+1 week';
                break;
            case '3':
                $period = '+1 month';
                break;
            case '4':
                $period = '+3 months';
                break;
            case '5':
                $perion = '+1 year';
                break;
            default:
                $period = null;
                break;
        }

        $dates = [];

        if($period !== null) {
            for($date = $startdate; $date < strtotime('+1 month', $startdate); strtotime($period, $date)) {
                $dates[] = $date;
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($dates);
```

Comment: Where are you increasing `$date` in that loop?

Comment: `strtotime($period, $date)` $period has the increment

Comment: Check the documentation for `strtotime`. Does it modify the timestamp passed as its second argument?

Comment: Right... it doesn't (of course). Any idea how to approach this then?

Comment: I found it.. changing `strtotime($period, $date)` to `$date = strtotime($period, $date)` did the trick. Thanks! @Don'tPanic

Comment: Yep, that's right. And that should prevent the timeout. But there are a couple of other issues I noticed after commenting initially. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing `$date` with `$date = strtotime($period, $date)` in the increment part of the for loop should keep it from timing out, but there are a couple of other improvements that could be made.

First I'd recommend calculating your end date once before the loop to avoid extra `strtotime` calls each time it checks the continuation condition.

```
$end = strtotime("$startdate +1 month");
```

Then, set `$date = strtotime($startdate)` in the initialization part, or you'll get a date string instead of a timestamp as the first value in your `$dates` array.

```
for ($date = strtotime($startdate); $date < $end; $date = strtotime($period, $date)) {
    $dates[] = $date;
}
```